# SD card works only once in Kubuntu 9.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubuntu, sd-card, card-reader

I have a new MSI GX620 derived laptop, with an internal SD card reader. It works fine when I first insert a card. But when I "safely remove" the card with Dolphin, and stick in a new card, nothing happens. The SD card is not mounted and does not appear in fdisk -l (though I don't know if it's supposed to). It works again when I reboot.

This is my card reader:

```
07:00.1 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technologies, Inc. SD/MMC Host Controller [197b:2382]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device [1462:6510]                       
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx- 
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes                                                                
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17                                                                    
    Region 0: Memory at f9ffe800 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]                                   
    Capabilities: [a4] Power Management version 3                                                        
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)                   
        Status: D0 PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-                                                  
    Capabilities: [80] Express (v1) Endpoint, MSI 00                                                     
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us                        
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-                                      
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-                           
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-                                         
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes                                           
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr- TransPend-                          
        LnkCap: Port #1, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 unlimited, L1 unlimited    
            ClockPM- Suprise- LLActRep- BwNot-                                                   
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk-                              
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-                                       
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-           
    Capabilities: [94] Message Signalled Interrupts: Mask- 64bit- Queue=0/0 Enable-                      
        Address: fffffffc  Data: 0000                                                                
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci                                                                      
    Kernel modules: sdhci-pci                                                                            

07:00.2 SD Host controller [0805]: JMicron Technologies, Inc. Standard SD Host Controller [197b:2381] (prog-if 01)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device [1462:6510]                                          
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-     
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-      
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17                                                                         
    Region 0: Memory at f9ffe400 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]                                        
    Capabilities: [a4] Power Management version 3                                                             
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)                        
        Status: D0 PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-                                                       
    Capabilities: [80] Express (v1) Endpoint, MSI 00                                                          
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us                             
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-                                           
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-                                
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-                                              
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes                                                
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr- TransPend-                               
        LnkCap: Port #1, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 unlimited, L1 unlimited         
            ClockPM- Suprise- LLActRep- BwNot-                                                        
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk-                                   
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-                                            
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-                
    Capabilities: [94] Message Signalled Interrupts: Mask- 64bit- Queue=0/0 Enable-                           
        Address: fffffffc  Data: 0000                                                                     
    Kernel modules: sdhci-pci                                                                                 

07:00.3 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technologies, Inc. MS Host Controller [197b:2383]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device [1462:6510]                   
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx- 
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes                                                                
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 5                                                                     
    Region 0: Memory at f9ffe000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]                                   
    Capabilities: [a4] Power Management version 3                                                        
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)                   
        Status: D0 PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-                                                  
    Capabilities: [80] Express (v1) Endpoint, MSI 00                                                     
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us                        
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-                                      
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-                           
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-                                         
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes                                           
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr- TransPend-                          
        LnkCap: Port #1, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 unlimited, L1 unlimited    
            ClockPM- Suprise- LLActRep- BwNot-                                                   
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk-                              
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-                                       
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-           
    Capabilities: [94] Message Signalled Interrupts: Mask- 64bit- Queue=0/0 Enable-                      
        Address: fffffffc  Data: 0000                                                                

07:00.4 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technologies, Inc. xD Host Controller [197b:2384]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device [1462:6510]                   
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx- 
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes                                                                
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 5                                                                     
    Region 0: Memory at f9ffdc00 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]                                   
    Capabilities: [a4] Power Management version 3                                                        
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)                   
        Status: D0 PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-                                                  
    Capabilities: [80] Express (v1) Endpoint, MSI 00                                                     
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us                        
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-                                      
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-                           
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-                                         
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes                                           
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr- TransPend-                          
        LnkCap: Port #1, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 unlimited, L1 unlimited    
            ClockPM- Suprise- LLActRep- BwNot-                                                   
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk-                              
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-                                       
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-           
    Capabilities: [94] Message Signalled Interrupts: Mask- 64bit- Queue=0/0 Enable-                      
        Address: fffffffc  Data: 0000
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem with automount. Do other devices automount properly? (USB keys, external hard drives, etc.)

Comment: I have an USB stick which works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely file a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You could force a restart with,

```
sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart
```

Comment: Nope, no success